# Bootstrap v3.3.6 Dropdown not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNGCM.png)I am not understanding why the Bootstrap drop down menu is not working!!! I downloaded Bootstrap to develop a custom design. The carousel is working fine, but when you click on the drop-down button the dropdown-menu jumps to the left!!! If you have the files on your computer kindly review it because it's too much code to copy here, I just copied my html and part of the bootstrap.min.css ... any advice please???

```css
.dropdown-menu {
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1000;
 display: none;
 float: left;
 min-width: 160px;
 padding: 5px 0;
 margin: 2px 0 0;
 font-size: 14px;
 text-align: left;
 list-style: none;
 background-color: #fff;
 -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
 background-clip: padding-box;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
 border-radius: 4px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
 box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175)
}
.dropdown-menu.pull-right {
 right: 0;
 left: auto;
}
.dropdown-menu .divider {
 height: 1px;
 margin: 9px 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #e5e5e5
}
.dropdown-menu>li>a {
 display: block;
 padding: 3px 20px;
 clear: both;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 1.42857143;
 color: #333;
 white-space: nowrap
}
.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus, .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover {
 color: #262626;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #f5f5f5
}
.dropdown-menu>.active>a, .dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus, .dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #337ab7;
 outline: 0
}
.dropdown-menu>.disabled>a, .dropdown-menu>.disabled>a:focus, .dropdown-menu>.disabled>a:hover {
 color: #777
}
.dropdown-menu>.disabled>a:focus, .dropdown-menu>.disabled>a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: not-allowed;
 background-color: transparent;
 background-image: none;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false)
}
.open>.dropdown-menu {
 display: block;
 position:relative;
}
.open>a {
 outline: 0
}
.dropdown-menu-right {
 right: 0;
 left: auto
}
.dropdown-menu-left {
 right: auto;
 left: 0
}
.dropdown-header {
 display: block;
 padding: 3px 20px;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 1.42857143;
 color: #777;
 white-space: nowrap
}
.dropdown-backdrop {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 990
}
.pull-right>.dropdown-menu {
 right: 0;
 left: auto;

}
.dropup .caret, .navbar-fixed-bottom .dropdown .caret {
 content: "";
 border-top: 0;
 border-bottom: 4px dashed;
 border-bottom: 4px solid\9
}
.dropup .dropdown-menu, .navbar-fixed-bottom .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
 top: auto;
 bottom: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 2px
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie6 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="">
<!--<![endif]-->

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/full-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="footer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/ancor.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="nav.js"></script>

<body>


 <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>


<!-- Full Page Image Background Carousel Header -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide"> 
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators-hp">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>
  
  <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active"> 
      <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
      <div class="fill" style="background-image:url(images/home/canvas_hp_1600x900_New_Giulietta_v1_update.jpg);"></div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item"> 
      <!-- Set the second background image using inline CSS below. -->
      <div class="fill" style="background-image:url(images/model/giulietta/canvas-2_modelpage-newgiulietta.jpg);"></div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h2></h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Controls --> 
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"> <span class="icon-prev"></span> </a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"> <span class="icon-next"></span> </a> </div>
  
<div id="myCarousel2" class="carousel slide"> 
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators" style="display:none;">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  </ol>
  
  <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active"> 
      <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
      <div class="fill" style="background-image:url(images/model/giulietta/overview_modelapage-newgiulietta.jpg);"></div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <div class=" model__content left">
          <h2 class="content__title"> OVERVIEW </h2>
          <div class="content__text"> <span class="animated-line"></span>
            <p>REDEFINING STYLE</p>
          </div>
          <div class="content__descr">
            <p>With new sporty exterior details, enhanced onboard experience, new interior touches and extended engine range: The Alfa Giulietta has once again reinvented itself.<br>
              Even more sporty. Even more Alfa Romeo.</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="myCarousel3" class="carousel slide"> 
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel3" data-slide-to="0" class="active">style</li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel3" data-slide-to="1" >exteriors</li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel3" data-slide-to="2" >interiors</li>
    <li class="last" data-target="#myCarousel3" data-slide-to="3" >distinctive</li>
  </ol>
  
  <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active"> 
      <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
      <div class="fill" style="background-image:url(images/model/giulietta/style_modelpage-giulietta.jpg); background-position:bottom;"></div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <div class=" model__content left">
          <h2 class="content__title"> ENHANCED SPORTS STYLING </h2>
          <div class="content__text"> <span class="animated-line"></span>
            <p>DESIGN &amp; PERFORMANCE</p>
          </div>
          <div class="content__descr">
            <p>The New Alfa Giulietta with its timeless elegance provides authentic Alfa Romeo driving pleasure. Why not discover this Italian masterpiece for yourself?</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item"> 
      <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
      <div class="fill" style="background-image:url(images/model/giulietta/exteriors_modelpage-newgiulietta.jpg); background-position:bottom center;"></div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <div class=" model__content left">
          <h2 class="content__title"> EXTERIORS </h2>
          <div class="content__text"> <span class="animated-line"></span>
            <p>ALFA ROMEO'S DISTINCTIVE STYLING</p>
          </div>
          <div class="content__descr">
            <p>From first glance, the iconic grille reflects true Alfa Romeo DNA. Every innovation of the New Alfa Giulietta highlights an Italian passion for performance and style, such as the carbon effect headlights, oversized tail pipes, and range of distinctive alloy wheels to personalise your Alfa Romeo.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item"> 
      <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
      <div class="fill" style="background-image:url(images/model/giulietta/interiors_modelpage-newgiulietta.jpg); background-position:top center;"></div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <div class=" model__content color--light left">
          <h2 class="content__title"> INTERIORS </h2>
          <div class="content__text"> <span class="animated-line"></span>
            <p>IGNITE YOUR PASSION</p>
          </div>
          <div class="content__descr">
            <p>The interiors of the New Alfa Giulietta have been crafted with high quality materials such as the new Italian design upholstery and matte black grain dashboard. Refined elegance in true Alfa Romeo style.
              New Alfa Giulietta. Pure Sportiness. Pure Emotion. Pure Alfa Romeo.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item"> 
      <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
      <div class="fill" style="background-image:url(images/model/giulietta/uniqueness_modelpage-newgiulietta.jpg);"></div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <div class=" model__content left">
          <h2 class="content__title"> DISTINCTIVE </h2>
          <div class="content__text"> <span class="animated-line"></span>
            <p>DESIGN & PERFORMANCE</p>
          </div>
          <div class="content__descr">
            <p>The New Alfa Giulietta with its timeless elegance provides authentic Alfa Romeo driving pleasure. Why not discover this Italian masterpiece for yourself?</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<!-- jQuery --> 
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script> 

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript --> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<!-- Script to Activate the Carousel --> 
<script>
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: false //changes the speed
  
    })
     </script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you make a JS fiddle that replicates your error?

Comment: Put your application specific markup and CSS in [this site](http://www.bootply.com/new) and provide the link in your question.

Comment: `jQuery` included twice, once in header and then in footer, should be included one time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use **CDNs**:

From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp):

> **One advantage of using the Bootstrap CDN:** Many users already have
>   downloaded Bootstrap from MaxCDN when visiting another site. As a
>   result, it will be loaded from cache when they visit your site, which
>   leads to faster loading time. Also, most CDN's will make sure that
>   once a user requests a file from it, it will be served from the server
>   closest to them, which also leads to faster loading time.

You can replace your downloaded bootstrap file links with these CDNs:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I tried your code with these CDNs and it was working.

Comment: i downloaded the files because i need to customize them if i replace them with links it will be remotely and i can't edit them

Comment: @SandyGubran  Oh! May be you deleted some lines which might be the reason the dropdown was not working. Do you need to customize all the three files?

Comment: @SandyGubran Do not edit those bootstrap / jquery files, instead use your own separate **CSS** files. You can write `CSS ` with `!important` option which tells browser to give importance to that style.

Comment: NO :) i just edited some lines in the css file, bg color or font size etc am sure that i didn't delete anything

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with your script tags. Try using the CDN for jQuery and Bootstrap. This example works fine...

**Edit:**
If you need to override CSS you can do so by using the same class name and declaring the styles AFTER the Bootstrap styles. Example:

*Bootstrap style*

```
.dropdown-menu.pull-right {
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
}
```

*Custom style*

```
.dropdown-menu.pull-right {
    right: 20px;
}
```

If you need to increase the targeting use `!important`

```
.dropdown-menu.pull-right {
    right: 20px !important;
}
```

I would not recommend changing the Bootstrap files at all.

```html
<html>
<body>

  <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- jQuery --> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript --> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok i did.. but when you try to add a carousel it will not working!

Comment: When I delete the CSS you have above, it works. When I add it, I get the error in your pic. If you need to customize the CSS add a new CSS file below the Bootstrap styles and override them.

Comment: @SandyGubran I edited my answer to show CSS overriding.